# Add to shell context menu only in my app

Tags: c#, menu, contextmenu, windows-shell

In my .NET Framework 4 app, I display files, folders and other stuff that is not part of the file system.  For files and folders, I managed to display the Windows Shell context menu for that item, thanks to [this code on MSDN](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/showandtell/thread/3f553b23-fdb3-4355-8496-28a781b37f72).  (It still fails to display the Carbonite Shell Extension but I digress.)

My struggle is in adding my own submenu to the Shell context menu.  All of my research  alludes to so-called Shell *Extensions*, which, if I understand correctly, is a system-wide change.  I only want to add to the Shell context menu *when it is accessed from within my app*.

Grasping at straws, admittedly, I tried to add the following in the above class' `ShowContextMenu` method, just after it calls `QueryContextMenu`:

```
var mii = new MENUITEMINFO();
mii.cbSize = Marshal.SizeOf(mii);
mii.fMask = MIIM.SUBMENU | MIIM.STRING | MIIM.FTYPE | MIIM.ID;
mii.fType = MFT.BYPOSITION;
mii.wID = 0;
mii.hSubMenu = subMenu.Handle;
mii.dwTypeData = "Test";
var success = InsertMenuItem(pMenu, 0, true, ref mii);
```

but with no "success".  (`subMenu` is a `System.Windows.Forms.ContextMenuStrip` that I created earlier.)

My questions are:

1. Am I correct that what I am attempting is distinct from creating a Shell Extension?
2. Is this still considered to be dangerous activity from managed code, as per [this post](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/codefx/archive/2011/03/27/writing-windows-shell-extension-with-net-framework-4-c-vb-net-part-4-context-menu-handler-with-menu-item-bitmaps.aspx)?
3. How does one actually do this?

Comment: 1: No.  I would just test for a named mutex in QueryContextMenu.  One that only your app creates.

Comment: So even though I have a handle to a Shell context menu, I can't add to it just for that instance?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

OK, looks like it *is* possible to add custom menu items to the Windows Shell context menu, just in your app (no need to do anything that affects the entire Windows system).  Below is what I did.  Keep in mind that this answer should be taken in the context of the MSDN code first mentioned.  Here's the link again:

[ShellContextMenu class on MSDN](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/showandtell/thread/3f553b23-fdb3-4355-8496-28a781b37f72)

In that class, specifically, the method `ShowContextMenu`, is a call to `QueryContextMenu`, whose purpose I learned is to populate the menu with items--in this case, the appropriate Windows Shell menu items for the file/folder whose context menu is to be displayed.  After that call, I added the following code to add a submenu and a separator:

```
var mii = new MENUITEMINFO();
mii.fMask = MIIM.SUBMENU | MIIM.STRING | MIIM.FTYPE | MIIM.ID | MIIM.STATE | MIIM.BITMAP;
mii.fState = MFS.ENABLED;
mii.fType = MFT.STRING;
mii.wID = 0;    // Application-defined value that identifies the menu item.
mii.hSubMenu = **subMenu**.Handle;
mii.dwTypeData = Program.ShortTitle;
mii.cch = mii.dwTypeData.Length;
var bmp = new System.Drawing.Icon(ac.Properties.NeutralResources.MyAppIcon, 16, 16).ToBitmap();
this.hMyAppSubmenuIcon = bmp.GetHbitmap();
mii.hbmpItem = this.hMyAppSubmenuIcon;
mii.cbSize = Marshal.SizeOf(typeof(MENUITEMINFO));
var success = InsertMenuItem(pMenu, 0, true, ref mii);

mii = new MENUITEMINFO();
mii.fMask = MIIM.FTYPE;
mii.fType = MFT.SEPARATOR;
mii.cbSize = Marshal.SizeOf(mii);
success = InsertMenuItem(pMenu, 1, true, ref mii);
```

**subMenu** is of type `System.Windows.Forms.ContextMenu`.  In this way, the entire context menu is somewhat of a hybrid, consisting of both managed and unmanaged menu items.  So far, I don't see a problem with this; it just means that handling the selection of the two types of menu items must be done differently, as described below...

After inserting the managed item(s) to the menu, the `ShowContextMenu` method calls `TrackPopupMenu`.  For Shell menu items, the already-written class takes care of handling their selection.  For my own menu items, I had to take extra steps because  `TrackPopupMenu` is a Windows API function so it doesn't work very well with the managed submenu items' `Click` event.  You can hook up `Click` event handlers to your submenu items but when they are selected from the Shell context menu, their `Click` event doesn't fire.  I did still wire up their `Click` even because sometimes I just display my managed menu on its own.

To take action in response to the managed menu item selection from the Shell context menu, I used the return value of `TrackPopupMenu`, which is the resource ID of the menu item that was selected.  That's where things got a little roundabout.  When *creating* the managed context menu, each menu item has an index.  You can use this with the Windows API function [GetMenuItemID](http://pinvoke.net/default.aspx/user32/GetMenuItemID.html), which returns the resource ID of the menu item.  I inherited from the managed `ContextMenu` class and encapsulated a `Dictionary` that helped me to map from this resource ID to the menu item, to be later used just after the call to `TrackPopupMenu`.  For my purposes, that's all I needed in order to invoke the handler because in my app, I use a command pattern and I stored the command object in the menu item's `Tag`  property when creating the menu.  (Once the dictionary gave me the correct menu item, I was able to execute the corresponding handler by extracting the command object from the `Tag`).

This has been running fine for several days now.  If anyone see holes, like unmanaged resources that I should have cleaned up, please mention.